# Control plot width with shared legend when using grid_arrange_shared_legend or grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two plots that share the same legend. I want to present them side-by-side with one legend, but I would like the left plot to be narrower than the right plot.

If I use grid_arrange_shared_legend, I can't control the individual plot widths:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

cbPalette <- c("#d52b1e", "#176ca4", "#f7761b", "#734e9e", "#176ca4", "#f7761b", "#734e9e")

plotMeanShapes = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")

plotIndShapes = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")

plotMeanShapesLegend = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) 


grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(..., ncol = length(list(...)), nrow = 1, position = c("bottom", "right")) {

  plots <- list(...)
  position <- match.arg(position)
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position = position))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lheight <- sum(legend$height)
  lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
  gl <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme(legend.position="none"))
  gl <- c(gl, ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow)

  combined <- switch(position,
                     "bottom" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl),
                                            legend,
                                            ncol = 1,
                                            heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight)),
                     "right" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl),
                                           legend,
                                           ncol = 2,
                                           widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, lwidth)))

  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(combined)

  # return gtable invisibly
  invisible(combined)

}

ppi <- 600
pageWidth <- 5.75
pageHeight <- 3.5

png("shapesArranged1.png", width = pageWidth, height = pageHeight, units = 'in', res = ppi)
grid_arrange_shared_legend(plotMeanShapes, plotIndShapes, ncol = 2, nrow = 1, position = "right")
dev.off()
```

[image: made with grid_arrange_shared_legend]

I've tried to control individual plot widths using layout_matrix in arrangeGrob, but it doesn't work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

cbPalette <- c("#d52b1e", "#176ca4", "#f7761b", "#734e9e", "#176ca4", "#f7761b", "#734e9e")

plotMeanShapes = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")

plotIndShapes = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")

plotMeanShapesLegend = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) 

grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(..., ncol = length(list(...)), nrow = 1, position = c("bottom", "right")) {

  plots <- list(...)
  position <- match.arg(position)
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position = position))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lheight <- sum(legend$height)
  lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
  lay <- rbind(c(1,1,2,2,2,2))
  gl <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme(legend.position="none"))
  gl <- c(gl, ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow)

  combined <- switch(position,
                     "bottom" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl, layout_matrix = lay),
                                            legend,
                                            ncol = 1,
                                            heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight)),
                     "right" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl, layout_matrix = lay),
                                           legend,
                                           ncol = 2,
                                           widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, lwidth)))

  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(combined)

  # return gtable invisibly
  invisible(combined)

}

ppi <- 600
pageWidth <- 5.75
pageHeight <- 3.5

png("shapesArranged1.png", width = pageWidth, height = pageHeight, units = 'in', res = ppi)
grid_arrange_shared_legend(plotMeanShapes, plotIndShapes, ncol = 2, nrow = 1, position = "right")
dev.off()
```

I've tried using grid.arrange instead, but when I save the figure as a png, the legend comes out huge:

```
cbPalette <- c("#d52b1e", "#176ca4", "#f7761b", "#734e9e", "#176ca4", "#f7761b", "#734e9e")

plotMeanShapes = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")

plotIndShapes = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")

plotMeanShapesLegend = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) 

library(gridExtra)

g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  legend
}

legend <- g_legend(plotMeanShapesLegend)

ppi <- 600
pageWidth <- 5.75
pageHeight <- 3.5

lay <- rbind(c(1,1,2,2,2,3))
grid.arrange(plotMeanShapes, plotIndShapes, legend, layout_matrix = lay)

png("shapesArranged2.png", width = pageWidth, height = pageHeight, units = 'in', res = ppi)
grid.arrange(plotMeanShapes, plotIndShapes, legend, layout_matrix = lay)    
dev.off()
```

[image: made with grid.arrange]

I would like the width control of grid.arrange with the sensible legend size/placement of grid_arrange_shared_legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cowplot` is really good at this:

```
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_grey())

plot_grid(
  plotMeanShapes, 
  plotIndShapes, 
  get_legend(plotMeanShapes + theme(legend.position="right")),
  nrow = 1, rel_widths = c(3, 2, 1)
)
```

[image]

Just vary the `rel_widths` to get the sizes you need. You can align the plots nicely as well, if need be.

Answer (score 0):

it makes more sense to add widths and heights arguments,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

cbPalette <- c("#d52b1e", "#176ca4", "#f7761b", "#734e9e", "#176ca4", "#f7761b", "#734e9e")

plotMeanShapes = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")

plotIndShapes = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")

plotMeanShapesLegend = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, name="condition", labels = c("really really long text", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) 


grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(..., 
                                       ncol = length(list(...)), 
                                       nrow = 1, 
                                       widths = rep(1, ncol),
                                       heights = rep(1, nrow),
                                       position = c("bottom", "right")) {

  plots <- list(...)
  position <- match.arg(position)
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position = position))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lheight <- sum(legend$height)
  lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
  gl <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme(legend.position="none"))
  gl <- c(gl, list(widths = widths, heights = heights))

  combined <- switch(position,
                     "bottom" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl),
                                            legend,
                                            ncol = 1,
                                            heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight)),
                     "right" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl),
                                           legend,
                                           ncol = 2,
                                           widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, lwidth)))

  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(combined)

  # return gtable invisibly
  invisible(combined)

}

grid_arrange_shared_legend(plotMeanShapes, plotIndShapes, 
                           widths=c(2,1), nrow = 1, position = "right")
```

[image]